# Por divs ao lado com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, grid, html-tags, layout-responsivo

Tenho 5 divs, quero por elas alinhadas na mesma linha... Porém a div centra não fica alinhada...

```
<section class="content">

  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="  col-xs-2  ">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
      </a>
     </div>

      <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
      </a>
     </div>

      <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
      </a>
     </div>


  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row">

    <div class=" col-xs-2 ">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>

     <div class=" col-xs-2 ">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-xs-2 ">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=" torreDiv col-xs-2 ">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=" torreDiv col-xs-2 ">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-2 ">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

[image: Esta assim]

[image: Gostaria que ficasse assim]

Comment: Voce precisa desse labirinto/espaço entre as divs A->C ->D ->B->A  ? Se sim, qual o tamanho dos espaco?  Voce precisa que esse " div E" seja ao centro acima dos outros divs? Aguardo resposta para solucionar seu problema

Answer (score 5):

Vc pode pegar a `.row` do meio e colocar uma classe `.centro` nela. Depois vc `composition:absolute` vc coloca ela "flutuando" por cima das outras, e alinha ela verticalmente com `top` e `transform:translateY()`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Veja o código referente a imagem acima:**

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
}

.centro {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 2;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<section class="content">

    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>


        <div class="  col-xs-2  ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-xs-2  ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>


    </div>


    <div class="row centro">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="row">

        <div class=" col-xs-2 ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-xs-2 ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class=" torreDiv col-xs-2 ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class=" torreDiv col-xs-2 ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-2 ">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```